# Octopus deploy variables automation

Tags: octopus-deploy

Can I add variables without prompt to user before deploy a package. I want store all my variables under git project. So that my code and octopus variables are in the same place.

Comment: I don't think Octopus supports storing variables/step scripts/configurations to a source control as of current version. Maybe you could leave this to config transformations and keep Octopus variables to a "necessary" minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Just create powershell script to load variables from your file (which is in package) and set it as first step. See:
https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/variables/output-variables